# UITableView not reloaded in NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsoperation

I want to reload `UITableView` inside `NSOperation` used to update the `image upload progress`. For this am using `RQOperation` from [this link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/RequestQueue) which internally uses `NSOperation`.

Now the image gets uploaded with progress bar updated with each byte of data. But when I `popViewController`, and then again go to this `ViewController` where uploading is going on then the uploading goes on in background, but the `UITableView` is not reloaded.

I even tried to `reload the tableView on main thread` - still not working.

This is the code am using:

```
    //progress handler
            operation.uploadProgressHandler = ^(float progress, __unused NSInteger bytesTransferred, __unused NSInteger totalBytes) {

                //update progress
                float tb = totalBytes/1000000;
                _progressBytes[imgName] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f/%.2f",(float)bytesTransferred/1000000,(float)totalBytes/1000000];
                [_progressStatuses setValue:@(progress) forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",var_cnt]];

                _progressStatuses[imgName] = @(progress);

                NSLog(@"urlurlurl:::%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CACHE_PROGRESS_%@",imgName]);
                [ud setObject:_progressStatuses[imgName] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CACHE_PROGRESS_%@",imgName]];
                [ud synchronize];


                [self.tblFolders performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                            withObject:nil
                                         waitUntilDone:YES];
//                [self.tblFolders reloadData];


            };
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you check what thread it's being called on?

Comment: am calling tableView reload on main thread-`[self.tblFolders performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                            withObject:nil
                                         waitUntilDone:YES];` And pls let me know how do I check on which thread the operation block is called.

Comment: NSLog '[NSThread currentThread]`. Try using `dispatch_async`, not sure why but I've had issues before when using `performSelectorOnMainThread` to a table view